# Why are filters called filters?

Tags: set-theory, filters

Given a set $S$, a filter $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{P}(S)$ is a non-empty subset of the power set of $S$ that satisfies the follow conditions:

1. $\emptyset \not\in \mathcal{F}$
2. Given $A$, $B \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$
3. Given $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B$ such that $A \subset B$, then $B \in \mathcal{F}$

My question is: what is the intuition besides the name "filter"? Does $\mathcal{F}$ actually filters something? Why is it called like that?

Comment: You can see an earlier attempt to explain this in the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816362/meaning-behind-filter-in-set-theory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning behind Filter in Set Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816362/meaning-behind-filter-in-set-theory)

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot!

Comment: No, the linked question does not address the reason for the name.